# Apache says it's started but localhost does not load

Tags: macos, apache-http-server

I'm having a problem with apache2 server today. I just wont respons for localhost but it says it's started.

Env: Mac OSX.

I'm listening on 80 as specified in /private/etc/apache2 lines 51-53.

```
<IfDefine !MACOSXSERVER>
Listen 80
</IfDefine>
```

It seems my configuration is fine, I think:

```
$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Unix)
Server built:   Jul 12 2012 15:11:26

$ httpd -t
httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, 
using Firemac.local for ServerName
Syntax OK
```

When trying to do

```
sudo apachectl restart
```

There is no error, and when I try

```
sudo apachectl start
```

I get

```
org.apache.httpd: Already loaded
```

127.0.0.1 and localhost do not respond. If I:

```
 $ lsof | grep LISTEN
```

or:

```
 $ netstat -l | grep http
```

There is nothing on port :80 listening, and if I:

```
 ps ax | grep httpd | grep -v grep
```

I get nothing.

Comment: Does `GET<enter><enter>` with `netcat 127.0.0.1 80` return anything? If so, try with `localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1` as well. Please share your complete configuration file if possible.

Comment: @zmode I just fixed it by rebuilding the config file from the default one and restarting the server at each changed line. The problem was in the vhosts file where I had foo1.dev.bar.com and foo2.dev.bar.com in two different virtual hosts directives - this is the way it should be. I just commented out the foo2.dev.bar.com alias and it worked. Not sure why...